# Unable to sort and query, SQL database Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to understand the dynamics of mysql, And I'm not able to understand this error statement:

Query:-

```
SELECT employee_id, First_name, Salary AS Pay FROM employee
ORDER BY Salary DESC
WHERE Salary > 70000
LIMIT 3;
```

I want to retrieve data from the `employee` table and then sort it up & only take out only the ones which are `greater than 7000`. But instead i Get this error,

> ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE Salary > 70000 LIMIT 3' at line 1

But , If the code is written this way,

```
SELECT employee_id, First_name, Salary AS Pay FROM employee
WHERE Salary > 70000
ORDER BY Salary DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

It runs, perfectly. But the query has a complete different meaning.

I hope you can understand what i mean,
Why can't we query after sorting the table?

Comment: `WHERE` goes before `ORDER BY`.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can sort before you select by a trick of sub selecting ie:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT employee_id, First_name, Salary AS Pay FROM employee
ORDER BY Salary DESC) a
WHERE Pay > 70000
LIMIT 3;
```

Mysql will first create a temporary memory table with ordered content and then your where will be applied to that table as will the limit.

Comment: This is the best solution, exactly what I was looking for, but just a small addition:

Comment: In line 3, it must be WHERE Pay> 70000

Answer (score 2):

SQL is a *descriptive* language, not a *procedural* language.

A SQL query describes the result set.  Whether you remove rows with `salary > 7000` and *then* sort, or sort and *then* remove them, you actually get the same answer.

You don't get to specify the order of operations; that is the job of the SQL compiler and optimizer.